# notifyDataSetChanged() won't update view if with DBHelper?

Tags: java, android

The following code updates the `gridView` automatically when I delete the `button`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Item item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_button, parent, false);
        }
        Button itemBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemBtn);
        itemBtn.setText(item.getName() + " (" + item.getPrice()+")");
        itemBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     MainActivity.cart.addItem(item);
                }
        });

    itemBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                remove(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });
       itemBtn.setLongClickable(true);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

but as I need to update the database as well, here is my current code now. The `view` does not update automatically and I still have to change tabs for the `gridView` to be updated and the `button` be removed.

```
itemBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(mActivity);
        if (dbHelper.removeData(item.getName(), item.getType()) > 1) {
            remove(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No such item to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        dbHelper.close();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure, dbHelper.removeData() returns a value greater than 1, so the body of the if-statement is actually executed?

Answer (score 0):

if did not update data then create a method in class or fragment which is load adapter again when long press then call this method instead of notifydatasetchanged

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Code inside `if statement` does not run. I thought I was checking all along with the `Toast.makeText()` and was so sure that it was indeed running because toast would not show, until I had realized that I forgot to call `.show()`. Sorry for the stupid mistake, I already found the problem.